# Pie Chart with 2 String columns and 1 int column in python

Tags: python, dataframe, pie-chart

I have a dataset as shown in the following figure:
[image]

I want to visualize those columns "release_year", "top", "freq" using the pie chart
My idea is to draw this pie chart using the x = df['freq'] and labels = df['top'] and then add a side color bar that shows the year according to the color, as:
red-color: 1970
yellow-color: 1971
and so on
to make it easier for the reader to understand the frequent use of each top in each year.

this is the pie chart I have created

[image]

now the user wont know the year of each section

Comment: Just add the legend and it is done. What is the problem?

Comment: @alec_djinn thnx I couldn't find this attribute in the pie chart description.

Comment: Are you using matplotlib? If so, check here https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html Else, can you share your plotting code?